# Had UIViewController embedded in navigation controller, but removed navigation controller for a manual UINavigationBar, but it errors out now

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, uitableview

What exactly am I doing wrong?

I have a storyboard with a UITableViewController embedded in a navigation controller, which has buttons in the bar connection to methods. I disconnected the methods and removed the bar and added a new UINavigationBar in (basically because I only wanted the navigation bar in that main view anyway, my app really doesn't have a hierarchy).

I get this error, though, when the app launches:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[RootViewController
>   topViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8341290'

What am I doing to cause that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in your app you are asking what *would* have been your UINavigationController for it's `topViewController`. Search your project for `topViewController` and see how you can adapt to not having a navigation controller in your hierarchy.

Comment: It's used here: `RootViewController *controller = (RootViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;` how do I fix that?

Comment: @DougSmith Just removing the `.topViewController` should fix the problem.